# Why is this onclick event handler not working?

Tags: events, event-handling, onclick, inline, outline

I am new to JS and trying to learn event handlers.  i've been looking at this for hours and I think it is way simpler than I am finding it.  Does anyone know why nothing happens when I click the button?

```
<script>
    function buttonClick(){
        document.getElementById("testButton").onclick = document.write("The button has been clicked!!!");
    }
    window.onload=buttonClick;
</script>
```

```
<input type="button" id="testButton" value="click me" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you need a function to assign onclick to, so this would work

```
 document.getElementById("testButton").onclick = function(){document.write("The button has been clicked!!!");}
```

that's an anonymous function.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  It worked.  So if I assign an onclick event through the getElementById method, I need to create an anonymous function?

Comment: Not exactly. You can assign to another function.
`document.getElementById('testButton').onclick = RandomFunc();`
`function RandomFunc() { alert('a'); }`

Comment: @AndréSilva, document.getElementById('testButton').onclick = RandomFunc(), you can do this, but you don't put () after RandomFunc, it wants the function reference not the function result.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. Sorry about that. Don't fully read what I wrote. Haha. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is loading the buttonClick event on the page load. you need to remove that line and add an onClick to your input. You could write it this way:

```
<script>
function buttonClick(){
    document.write("The button has been clicked!!!");
}
</script>

<input type="button" id="testButton" value="click me" onClick="buttonClick()" />
```